# How to use date range picker of Ant Design Vue component library together with data-fns?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, antd, ant-design-vue

Is there a way how to import data-range (using date-fns) component in Vue 3 using Ant Design component library? I am able to import date-picker, but not range-picker.

```
import ADatePickerFns from "ant-design-vue/es/date-picker/date-fns";
```

I tried everything, search everywhere - but without success. Can anybody help? Thanks a lot!